# Android tabs method invocation

Tags: android, tabs

When tabs clicked, how can I leave the same contentView, and only invoke a method that apply a filter on my list changing the elements? If I don't set the "setContent" attribute I get "you must specify a way to create the tab content", but I don't want to create a new view only for some changes into the list!

Here class that create and control tabs

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.implant_fragment, container, false);

    // Take implant listView
    _lv_imp = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    _tabHost = (TabHost) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    // Tab1
    TabHost.TabSpec todoImpTab = _tabHost.newTabSpec("todo");
    // set title and icon
    todoImpTab.setIndicator("Impianti DA FARE");

// ******** Here invoke the method for change the content of listView when tab clicked ****
    filterTodoImplant();

    // Tab2
    TabHost.TabSpec allImpTab = _tabHost.newTabSpec("all");
    allImpTab.setIndicator("TUTTI gli impianti");

    listDBImplants();

    // Add tabspec to tabHost
    _tabHost.addTab(todoImpTab);
    _tabHost.addTab(allImpTab);

    return view;
}
```

Here the layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Fragment container -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<!-- Tab host for filter list elements -->
<TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<!-- nav drawer list -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv_drawer_list"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:background="#2A262F" />
```

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent%28int%29 and specify the same id of the content view for all tabs. You can then call the method in the TabListener.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog, now i'm getting null pointer on TabHost, but i think is something concern fragments.